# How to know if push notification recieved

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I'm using push notification on my app.
I'm executing some logic when my app is opened via notification; 
I'm using for it

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

method.

Can I know, when my app recieving notification, without oppening it?

Comment: That method will be called, if the payload is appropriate, before the user is notified that the message is received. I'm not clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push a local notification when your app is in background or inactive, so you can see the push content, no to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the delegate method you posted will be called when the system receives a notification. You can use the userInfo dictionary to acces the content of the notification.

Comment: Yes. But I'm asking - Is there a method to know that app recived push

Comment: This delegated method is called when the app is closed and receive a notification. I don't understand your problem, sorry